# Multiple questions related to Actor-based model

Tags: function, actor, computation, computability, actor-model

I have been told to write a paper that works as a review for Hewitt Actor-based model where I have to include:

a) Hewwit actor-model definition (done, with explanations about how "actors" work; disallow shared memory, etc).

b) Calculus example => I don't have any clues if I should investigate lambda calculus, pi calculus or even A-pi calculus as defined by Gul Agha in 2004.

c) Definition of computable function => No clues. As far as I know, a computable function is defined as a function that is Turing-computable; but at the same time I read that Actor-model is an improvement of Turing's model; in a sense that Turing machines can't compute actor's related functions because they have no bound.

d) Describe relations with other computation models (easy, Actor-model vs Turing's model and I have it).

Some clarifications related with b) and c) in a way where I can expand those sections. Some websites, papers or explanations would be highly appreciated.